# Why is my ASP function not returning the link inside the A Href?

Tags: asp-classic

Good Morning,

I'm currently writing a Classic ASP function to amend a URL but adding in the product name to enhance the links strength. I have managed to get the link correct but it's not being placed within the HREF, it's displaying as a URL.

To explain this better please see the example below:

Take a look at the first category output:
http://www.dibor.co.uk/sitemap.asp

The function:

```
function URLName(var1,var2)
    dim nameString
    dim scString
    scString = UCase(var2)
    nameString = var1
    nameString = Replace(nameString," ","-")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"'","")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"!","")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"&","and")
    varString = LCase(nameString)
    response.write("http://www.dibor.co.uk/Product.asp?ProductId=" & scString & "&title=" & varString)
end function
```

Output Code:

```
Response.Write "<li><a href='" & 
    URLName(LivingRoomFurniture.fields("ProductTitle"), 
    LivingRoomFurniture.fields("StockCode")) & "'>" & 
    LivingRoomFurniture.fields("ProductTitle") & "</a> - " & 
    FormatCurrency(LivingRoomFurniture.fields("Price"),2) &"</li>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a value from a function, you assign it to the function name; using `response.write` in the function writes out the URL before the output code executes. In other words, your fix should be:

```
function URLName(var1,var2)
    dim nameString
    dim scString
    scString = UCase(var2)
    nameString = var1
    nameString = Replace(nameString," ","-")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"'","")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"!","")
    nameString = Replace(nameString,"&","and")
    varString = LCase(nameString)
    URLName = "http://www.dibor.co.uk/Product.asp?ProductId=" & scString & "&title=" & varString
end function
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks for that, new to ASP!